# Haskell Servant: How to deal with invalid Accept header (or ignore it completely)

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm writing a webhook endpoint (receiving end) and don't really have control over the incoming `Accept` header in the request. Here's what it is:

```
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

I've tried `Post '[JSON, HTML, PlainText] Text` but it results in a `406` status code.

IIUC, Servant is unable to parse this as a valid `Accept` header due to the `*` (which should probably be `*/*`) and the `q=.2` (which should probably be `q=0.2`

How do I deal with this? The realistic situation is that I don't care about the `Accept` header, and the webhook sender doesn't really care about the response body (only the response code matters)

I found `Network.HTTP.Media.Accept.Accept` which has `parseAccept :: ByteString -> Maybe a`, which I tried using like this...

```hs
data IrrelevantAcceptHeader = IrrelevantAcceptHeader deriving (Show)

instance Network.HTTP.Media.Accept.Accept IrrelevantAcceptHeader where
  parseAccept _ = Just IrrelevantAcceptHeader
  matches _ _ = True
  moreSpecificThan _ _ = False
  hasExtensionParameters _ = True

instance Servant.Accept IrrelevantAcceptHeader where
  contentType _ = fromString "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2"

instance MimeRender IrrelevantAcceptHeader Text where
  mimeRender _ txt = toS txt

-- and here's how it's used:

data Routes route = Routes
  { rWebhook 
    :: route 
    :- "webhook" 
    :> Header' '[Required, Strict] "X-Api-Secret" Text 
    :> ReqBody '[JSON] Aeson.Value 
    :> Post '[IrrelevantAcceptHeader] Text
  } deriving (Generic)
```

...but all this jugglery doesn't really work!

PS: This might be related to [Haskell Servant (client): UnsupportedContentType error due to weird Accept header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134030/haskell-servant-client-unsupportedcontenttype-error-due-to-weird-accept-heade)

Comment: How are you using `IrrelevantAcceptHeader`? Just defining the type (and its instances) is almost certainly not enough (barring some Template Haskell tomfoolery).

Comment: @DanielWagner updated the question to specify how `IrrelevantAcceptHeader` is used, i.e. `Post '[IrrelevantAcceptHeader] Text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider writing a `Middleware` to fix up the broken `Accept` header before it's passed to `servant`.  This would affect all routes, but that's probably what you want anyway.

It would look something like:

```
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header

fixAccept :: Middleware
fixAccept app req
  = app (req { requestHeaders = map fixAcceptHeader (requestHeaders req) })
  where fixAcceptHeader (key, value) 
          | key == hAccept = (hAccept, value)  -- do something to "value" here
        fixAcceptHeader other = other
```

and when you run your Servant server, just wrap it in the middleware:

```
main :: IO ()
main = run 8080 (fixAccept app1)
```

If you want to check in your Middleware whether or not a header fix is necessary, note that Servant uses `matchAccept` from `Network.HTTP.Media` in the `http-media` package which in turn uses `parseQuality` to do the matching.  You can check in the middleware if `parseQuality` succeeds or fails:

```
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings
λ> import Data.ByteString
λ> import Network.HTTP.Media
λ> parseQuality "Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2" :: Maybe [Quality ByteString]
Nothing
λ> parseQuality "Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=0.2, */*; q=0.2" :: Maybe [Quality ByteString]
Just [Accept: text/html;q=1,image/gif;q=1,image/jpeg;q=1,*;q=0.2,*/*;q=0.2]
```

As above, it appears to be the invalid quality numbers specifically that are causing problems.

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/zmthy/http-media/issues/28) that, unfortunately, the developers are refusing to fix.  Fortunately, `http-media` is open source with a permissive license, so you are free to patch it yourself for your own use or for redistribution.

Comment: I was afraid to get this answer. This makes `servant` to use very problematic in real-life/pragmatic scenarios because of its insistence on implementing content-type negotiation so strictly. Would you, by any chance, know which function inside `servant` parses the accept header? Is there any way to know (inside the middleware) if the Accept header parsing has not worked? Only then apply a fix?

Comment: See the update at the end.